# Shiro different cookies for different realms

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, shiro

Assume my app handles two specific url patterns

- /foo/* -> Only FooUsers will have access, authenticated in FooUserRealm
- /bar/* -> Only BarUsers will have access, authenticated in BarUserRealm

I can handle selection of correct realm by means of assigning two seperate authc filters to these url patterns and creating two different authentication token instances, then realms just have to declare which token type they support.

But, what I cannot achieve is that after authenticated FooUsers will have access to /bar/* urls and vice versa. What I really want to achieve is that there are two seperate cookies for each realm and when a FooUser tries to access /bar/* urls, she is redirected to BarUser login page. Only after a user is both authenticated with FooUser and BarUser realms (credentials need not be the same, so an authentication policy doesnot help here, users have to see two seperate login pages if they want to access /foo/* and /bar/*)

I can only think of creating two seperate security managers creating different cookies for these realms and url patterns.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: It sounds like two apps? I wouldn't create two SecurityManagers - A whole world of pain because they are based on ThreadLocals.

Comment: Perhaps expand on your question about what the realms are, and I might be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no simple way. One security manager means one SessionManager. One SessionManager means one cookie.

The only thing I can think of using one SecurityManager is writing your own SessionManager implementation and injecting that into your RealmSecurityManager, but as dom farr suggests, you're probably into a world of pain because of the way sessions are coupled to ThreadLocals.

So if I were you I would create two distinct SecurityManagers and each have their own cookie id set on the SessionManager.